# Kibana and Docker-Compose: Automatically load in saved object

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana-5

> **Goal**: Load in Kibana saved object when starting Elastic Stack from Docker-Compose.

I have an "export.json" object from Kibana, containing my default index, 10+ visualizations, and dashboard setup. I am able to successfully start the Elastic Stack from Docker-Compose and manually load the object, but it does not load it automatically upon container start.

I need to find a method to load this object programmatically, as I will have multiple objects that can be deployed depending on the containers running. In other words (using pseudo-config):

```
test1
    container a           # code to run
    container b           # code send metrics
    test1_export.json     # display metrics
test2
    container c           # code to run
    container d           # code send metrics
    test2_export.json     # display metrics
```

Using these definitions:

```
 > run test1
```

Would execute two Docker-Compose files, one to run code and the other to run the Elastic Stack. The latter would also need to load in the export.json object.

#### What I've attempted so far

This method was eluded to from [this config file](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml#L28):

> Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.

Also from [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana-docker/issues/21):

> Kibana keeps all its state in Elasticsearch, specifically in the .kibana index. There should be no need to preserve any state on the local file system of the Kibana containers.

However, Kibana starts from scratch whenever I restart my containers.

Taken directly from this Kibana user guide, I attempted to store the kibana.yml config file within the container. However, this syntax breaks Kibana upon start. Here are the two files:

**kibana.yml**

```
kibana.index: ".kibana"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    elasticsearch: 
        container_name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"
        expose:
            - 9200
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - "transport.host=127.0.0.1"
            - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
        volumes:
            - "./elasticsearch/data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"

    logstash:
        container_name: logstash
        build: ../../modules/logstash
        image: logstash:5.5.1

    kibana: 
        container_name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.5.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "5601:5601" 
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
        environment:
            - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200"
        expose:
            - 5601
        volumes:
            - "./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml"
```

---

My questions:

- What am I doing now that's incorrect (to just preserve Kibana)?
- How can I load a "export.json" file using Docker-Compose? Ideally I'd like to be able to define a volume in Docker-Compose to the path where Kibana looks for objects.

My environment is Linux/Centos7.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue with Docker. One solution are short lived containers to configure everything the way you want it; for example running a shell script.

Take a look at Elastic's stack demo, where they are just [using this approach](https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L94-L103).

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
  # Run a short-lived container to set up Logstash.
  setup_logstash:
    image: centos:7
    volumes: ['./scripts/setup-logstash.sh:/usr/local/bin/setup-logstash.sh:ro']
    # The script may have CR/LF line endings if using Docker for Windows, so
    # make sure that they don't confuse Bash.
    command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'cat /usr/local/bin/setup-logstash.sh | tr -d "\r" | bash']
    environment: ['ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}']
    networks: ['stack']
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch']
```

*setup-logstash.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

es_url=http://elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}@elasticsearch:9200

# Wait for Elasticsearch to start up before doing anything.
until curl -s $es_url -o /dev/null; do
    sleep 1
done

# Set the password for the logstash_system user.
# REF: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.0/setting-up-authentication.html#set-built-in-user-passwords
until curl -s -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
     -XPUT $es_url/_xpack/security/user/logstash_system/_password \
     -d "{\"password\": \"${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}\"}"
do
    sleep 2
    echo Retrying...
done
```

Run whatever cURL command you need to configure Kibana the way you want it.

Answer (score 1):

--> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

I would recommend taking ELK to this site as a guide. I have installed this site and I am very satisfied.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm looking for at all.