# How to set Kibana default route in docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, environment-variables, kibana

How would you configure the Kibana default route (default: /app/home) in a docker-compose.yml file, using environnement variable ?

I tried :

- defaultRoute=/app/discover
- DEFAULTROUTE=/app/discover
- KIBANA_DEFAULTROUTE=/app/discover
- uiSettings.overrides.defaultRoute=/app/discover
- UISETTINGS_OVERRIDES_DEFAULTROUTE=/app/discover

but nothing works.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an officially documented way to do this via an environment variable or even via the API however the following API call works on Kibana 7.17 & 8.7:

```bash
curl -X POST http://kibana:5601/api/kibana/settings \
     -H "kbn-xsrf: true" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"changes":{"defaultRoute":"/app/discover"}}'
```

So to use this in a docker compose file, set up a service which runs a short-lived container (basically anything that has `curl` available) to wait for Kibana to be up and then run the above, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054815/528711).